# Compiler can't find installed library headers

Tags: c, compiler-errors, header-files

Writing my first application in C and it can't seem to find the header file (which I installed following the instructions in the readme):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ftdi.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
int ret;
struct ftdi_context = *ftdi;
struct ftdi_version_info version;
if ((ftdi = ftdi_new()) == 0)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "ftdi_new failed\n");
}
else {
    fprintf(stderr, "Success\n");
}
return 0;
}
```

But it finds it here:

```
ollieb@ursus ~/Documents/BitBang $ locate ftdi.h
/home/ollieb/.local/share/Trash/files/libftdi/libftdi/ftdipp/ftdi.hpp
/home/ollieb/.local/share/Trash/files/libftdi/libftdi/src/ftdi.h
/home/ollieb/Applications/libftdi1-1.3/build/doc/html/group__libftdi.html
/home/ollieb/Applications/libftdi1-1.3/build/doc/man/man3/ftdi.h.3
/home/ollieb/Applications/libftdi1-1.3/build/doc/man/man3/ftdi.hpp.3
/home/ollieb/Applications/libftdi1-1.3/ftdipp/ftdi.hpp
/home/ollieb/Applications/libftdi1-1.3/src/ftdi.h
/usr/include/libftdi1/ftdi.h
/usr/include/libftdi1/ftdi.hpp
```

This is what happens when I try to compile, it says the file cannot be found (when I run examples in the code library folder they run fine):

```
ollieb@ursus ~/Documents/BitBang $ make
make bitbang
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/ollieb/Documents/BitBang'
cc -Wall -g     bitbang.c   -o bitbang
bitbang.c:3:18: fatal error: ftdi.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
<builtin>: recipe for target 'bitbang' failed
make[1]: *** [bitbang] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/ollieb/Documents/BitBang'
Makefile:4: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: What's the exact error message?

Comment: Your `ftdi.h` copies (*that are many*) are in non standard locations, the compiler only searches on some places for headers. You need to add the path in you compiler command, most likely `-I/usr/include/libftdi1` will work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, compiler searches for the header files in the default INCLUDE path, not the whole filesystem.

If you have your headers in a custom path, you need to inform the compiler about that. For example, with `gcc` and `clang`, you can use the `-I` switch to let the compiler know the path where the header files are present.

From [gcc online manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Directory-Options.html#Directory-Options),

> `-Idir`
>   Add the directory `dir` to the head of the list of directories to be searched for header files. [...]

Comment: So how would I add that to my make file?

Comment: Thanks @iharob for the addition. :)

Comment: Yes I think the clang compiler is very common on OS X.

Comment: @ollie299792458 You have to supply that option in the compilation statement.

Comment: As in, do I put it on the same line as `CFLAGS=-Wall -g` or after `all: make bitbang`

Comment: @iharob why would that be relevant?

Comment: @ollie299792458 If someone is using *clang* and reads in the answer *gcc* they will have to google something like *How to specify include paths for clang* or similar. Instead, since they use the same flags for almost everything, I think it's helpful if the answer explicitly says that. Remember that someone who asked about this, very likely doesn't know about the differences and similarities between these compilers. And since this OP is apparently on a OS X system, and *clang* is the main compiler used there, I thought it'd be helpful.

Comment: @iharob Fair enough